# Delete directory from public folder in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I have saved the images folder in public/uploads/portfolio. and I need to remove the portfolio directory with images when I call destroy method. I tried the unlink method but it cannot use to remove the entire directory. is there any other solution for this? my laravel version is 8.0

I have tried this code but it throws an error

```
 public function destroy()
    {
        $imagepath = public_path().'/uploads/portfolios';
        unlink($imagepath);
    }
```

Comment: please add the exception error in your question

Comment: it shows the target is a directory. however, I have changed the controller to remove images without removing the directory. that's some kind of solution for this time. 
 @Psycho